# Different background for each page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find the easiest way to give each page (from my NavBar) in my website a 'different' photo-background. It seems that once a background is selected that it remains constant for all subsequent pages.

I have Home, About and Contact me links in my NavBar. **My goal is to have one photo-background when visitors click on my Home page, another photo-background when they click on About page, third photo-background when they click on my Contact page, etc.**

Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
body {background-image:url(greentea.jpg);}
```

Comment: make inline style sheets for all pages

Comment: I'd be cautious about too many photo backgrounds: it might look pretty but does nothing to make a site easier to use

Comment: One of the easy ways would be to name the background files same as your page and using a single JavaScript script to do it for you everytime.

Comment: Hi! I am just a beginner in HTML and CSS. I heard that it is better to do CSS separately. Could you please be more specific and maybe give me an example how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign class to body like

for homepage

```
<body class="home">
```

for about us page

```
<body class="about">
```

The you can use css

```
body.home{background-image:url(greentea.jpg);}
body.about{background-image:url(greentea.jpg);}
```

Comment: I choose ID, because you won't have another about page nor another home page. There is only one. Classnames are better for <body class="marketing-page" where more than one page will get the style.

Comment: You can go either way but sometime you may require body id for some javascript crap so better stay on safe side.

Comment: What JS specifically? document.body gives you the body.

Comment: The way we do CSS scoping on our site recognizeapp.com, home.scss is #home {/*all home scoped css goes here*/}, etc for all pages. Keeps things isolated.

Comment: as i said we can go either way

Answer (score 3):

Give each  tag a unique page ID. In our app we use ruby on rails, so it is id="<%=controller-view%>" kind of architecture.

If your site is static, just hard code in the ID.

```
<body id="about">
```

Then in the CSS

```
body#about {background...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I choose to do that, is to assign a different class on the `<body>` element depending on the current page.

That way you can use CSS to target each page with page specific assets, such as background in a maintainable fashion.

Is most CMSs you could just use the id of the page ( be it a slug, a node id, or even a sanitized path ).

Comment: I think this might work. So, if I assign a different class on the <body> element in each of my pages (Home, About, Contact) then I can add all those classes to my stylesheet and it should work just fine. Am I right?

Comment: you'd just add something like `body.page1 { /* Styles here */ }` and or your could target descendants, such as `body.page1 .someclass`

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS line that you have already (`body {background-image:url(greentea.jpg);}`) on each page in it's `<head><style></style></head>` tags and just change the background image on every page. Be aware that it is advised to have a separate CSS file to avoid any inline styling.